# Anyone ever run this script? Where do I do password/username/etc modification?

Tags: python

https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/login.py

I am trying to write a python script that will add a custom field to every account and lead object in a customer salesforce.

Comment: check out lines 18-20

Answer (score 1):

It's actually basically in the comments.

```
# python
username = "you@org"
password = "correct horse battery staple"
security_token = "randomlettersandnumb3rs"
org_id = "00D-restoforgid"
session_id, sf_instance = SalesforceLogin(username=username, password=password, security_token=security_token, org_id=org_id)
```

Once logged in, you can use those two variables to call other methods, such as the metadata API.

Personally, if you can help it, I'd recommend Java or C#, since the manual already has documentation and sample code on how to do stuff.

Comment: [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/936/) password heh.